# Getting Folder size sort by size including too long path name

Tags: windows, powershell

**Task:** Display main folders in C:\temp, (Sorted by top / size) , the c:\temp folder have lots of sub folders inside it, long paths too.

like

```
c:\temp
c:\temp\folder1
c:\temp\folder1\sub_folder
c:\temp\folder2
c:\temp\folder2\sub_folder_more_folder_long_folders_files_names_as_well
```

I want to Display folders listing like this

```
Name     Type        Size
folder1  Directory   10
folder2  Directory   12
```

I am using following powershell script to get the folder name along with size , Sorted by size, and in end Display only top 20 folders.

```
ls c:\temp | select Name,
    @{
        Name="Type";Expression={
            if($_.psIsContainer)
            {
                "Directory"
            }
            else
            {
                "File"
            }
        }
    },
    @{
        Name="Size(GB)";
        Expression=
        {
            [Math]::Round($(ls $_.FullName -recurse| measure Length -sum).Sum/1GB, 3)
        }
    } | sort -property "Size(GB)" -desc | Select -First 20
```

This gives me results,

```
    USER1          Directory                       11.166
    USER2          Directory                       2.917
    USER3          Directory                       0.042

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
```

As I can see it also gives error of long path names, how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: did you try to use `.ShortName` instead of `.FullName`... ? BTW even if it works now, _deeper_ it could still happens.

Comment: If I used `.ShortName` , all folders showing the same size

Comment: What you are trying to do it's really similar to the Linux `du -hs | sort -n`. You can see some implementation in powershell on the net. For example [on this blog page](http://langexplr.blogspot.ru/2007/03/implementation-of-du-s-in-powershell.html) or in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/868290/3569208). Check if you overcome your problem and remember you can always install [coreutils for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not have paths that are that deep. Various application will or will not be able to access them and it comes down to the implementation of said application.

That said you could look into [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/232986/overcoming-maximum-file-path-length-restrictions-in-windows) question and more specifically into the `\\?` notation [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) and check whenever you can circumvent the limitation using PS with that.

Comment: The target is to list top folders size with there names only. (sort by size) , this main folder is shared in d:\users
unfortunately it is hard to force users to use short names, as they have lots of research papers and for easy tagging they use long characters.

Comment: If they're using Windows it's likely that those files are already inaccessible for them in various applications but as I was expecting that you wouldn't be able to easily change that, I included the second bit of information. It really should include all the tools you can use, after all it also includes the "not so well" supported registry fix.

Comment: following is a kind of report I wanted for my users folders.
[https://aacable.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/1.png ]

Comment: Linux powered PowerShell? If you're using Lotus why not use ]the build in reporting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_GENERATING_MAIL_USAGE_REPORTS_FROM_THE_DOMINO_ADMINISTRATOR_STEPS.html)? But even then ... did you just try to use a `\\?` path as the entry point or didn't you? Did you still get the same error or not? I don't really care for what kind of report you want as I merely pointed out a way to overcome the path limit.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the pointers. I will look into it.